# Does PHP's 'return' statement return a boolean by default?

Tags: php, return

I'm not quite sure how to ask this but, I have the following PHP function:

```
<?php

function checkAge($age) {
    return ($age >= 21); 
 }

?>
```

Which can be used on this conditional:

```
<?php

if(checkAge(21)) {
    echo 'welcome to the club';
}
else {
   echo 'sorry! you are younger than 21';

} 

?>
```

When defining the function, I'm only saying `return ($age >= 21)` and it seems to be returning 'true'. Does that mean that using `return` like that will return a boolean?

I'm sorry if I'm not being clear, this really confused me :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The short answer is yes. And actually when you do  `if ($age >= 21)`, `$age >= 21` will be evaluated first. And `if` uses this value to choose the branch.

Comment: The answers below tell you what you're looking for so I won't repeat that. But just out of curiosity it would be interesting to ask, what were you expecting that code to do, if not return a boolean?

Comment: @ADyson I'm taking an online course and the teacher said to build a function that would work for a night club, and tell you whether or not you're allowed to enter, based on your age. Following the teacher's logic I wrote the function and the conditional but I wasn't sure why it was working. I guess because I was thinking that the `return` statement itself was the one returning the boolean 'by default' (hence my question here), and didn't notice that it was actually the comparison expression `$age >= 21` like I just learned.

Answer (score 2):

`return` returns whatever you give to it. If what you give to it is an expression, the expression will be evaluated and its result will be returned. Here, you are returning an expression that evaluates to a boolean, so yes your function will return either true or false.
So your function `checkAge` is the same as:

```
// Just to explain. Don't do this!
function checkAge($age) {
    if ($age >= 21) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

But:

> Does PHP's 'return' statement return a boolean by default?
> No.

What you pass to it is what will be returned. If nothing was passed to it, `null` will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

`return` stops the execution of the current module and gives control back to the calling code. See - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php.

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
> ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
> the value of the function call.

The boolean that you're getting is from your comparison expression `$age >= 21`. Comparison expressions always return a boolean. See - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php#language.expressions

As an example, these 2 pieces of code are functionally identical. They both compare 2 values and return a boolean.

```
<?php

if ($age >= 21) {
    ...
}

if (checkAge(21)) {
    ...
}
```